# How to use Azure Shared Gallery VM image in Azure Batch Pool

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-batch

I have created a Shared image gallery from generalized VM and I am trying to use it in Azure batch pool creation. But I have not been successful. I am using C# for the Batch pool creation. Has any one done this before? Can someone give me some tips on how to succeed please?

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest C# SDK, as older SDK's use a REST API which doesn't support Shared Image Gallery. Then you should be able to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-custom-images. It may be helpful to share any errors you are receiving as well as the code you are using so that others have a point of reference to your experience/progress.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Brklein. That is what I am following. But it does not work. It is to do with permission I suspect. I think my Batch app needs to be registered with Azure AD. Did any one ever got this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right on the authentication,Applications that call the Azure Batch Management service authenticate with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD).

The Batch Management .NET library exposes types for working with Batch accounts, account keys, applications, and application packages. The Batch Management .NET library is an Azure resource provider client, and is used together with Azure Resource Manager to manage these resources programmatically. Azure AD is required to authenticate requests made through any Azure resource provider client, including the Batch Management .NET library, and through Azure Resource Manager.

In the below article , you can read more about the registering application and required permission for accessing Batch client:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-aad-auth-management

Your client application uses the application ID (also referred to as the client ID) to access Azure AD at runtime.

Once you have already authenticated with Azure AD with right permission set, you can use below code for performing the operation:

```
private static void CreateBatchPool(BatchClient batchClient, VirtualMachineConfiguration vmConfiguration)
{
    try
    {
        CloudPool pool = batchClient.PoolOperations.CreatePool(
            poolId: PoolId,
            targetDedicatedComputeNodes: PoolNodeCount,
            virtualMachineSize: PoolVMSize,
            virtualMachineConfiguration: vmConfiguration);

        pool.Commit();
    }
    ...
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-custom-images#create-a-pool-from-a-shared-image-using-c

You can browse below repo to understand it better:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-batch-samples/blob/master/CSharp/AccountManagement/Program.cs

Additionally , for opening a BatchClient connection you need to pass the BatchTokenCredentials:

```
public static Microsoft.Azure.Batch.BatchClient Open (Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Auth.BatchTokenCredentials credentials);
```

Additional Reference:

https://github.com/paulo-santos/azure-batch-samples/blob/master/CSharp/BatchExplorer/Service/BatchService.cs

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom pool by using shared image gallery, AAD authentication is required. You can register a service principal to do it as it is mentioned in the doc, [Authenticate Batch service solutions with Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-aad-auth#use-a-service-principal). It has the sample code in C#.

I also wrote a [post](https://chunliu.me/2020/03/28/azure-batch-create-a-custom-pool-using-shared-image-gallery/) about how to create a pool with sig. The sample code was in Python, but the idea behind is the same.